Как использовать 2 декоратора
Подскажите, как правильно использовать сразу два декоратора ?
В данном случае у меня либо отрабатывает один, либо другой декоратор
import logging

def decor(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       if type(func(*args, **kwargs)) == int:
           return f'Сумма чисел - {func(*args, **kwargs)}'
       else:
           return f'Получилось слово - {func(*args, **kwargs)}'
    return wrapper

def namefile():
    return __file__.split('\\')[-1]

def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        dirlog = r'D:\PYTHON\log.txt'
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(dirlog)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        logger.info(f'Скрипт - {namefile()} начал работу')
        
        func(*args, **kwargs)

        logger.info(f'Скрипт - {namefile()} завершил работу')

    return wrapper

@log
@decor
def sum(a, b):
    try:
        n = a + b
        return n
    except TypeError as e:
        logger.error(e)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        logger.error(e)

#print(sum('f',  'uck'))
print(sum(10,  10))


Если вы внутрь wrapper'ов добавите что-нибудь нормальное наподобие print('decor wrapper') и print('log wrapper') соответственно, то увидите, что оба таких принта сработают, а значит оба декоратора прекрасно отрабатывают

1 - в decor нужно вызывать функцию один раз. Вы зачем-то несколько раз вызываете. 2 - в декораторе log вы вообще не возвращаете то что вернула функция, в итоге wrapper возвращает None. 3 - в самой функции вы пытаетесь обратиться к logger, который функция не может видеть.

Получение имени файла будет работать только под windows. Чтобы было универсально, можно взять Path из стандартного модуля pathlib: Path(__file__).name

спасибо за инфу
